# Laravel - Stop Auto Login after Email Confirmation

Tags: laravel

In the Laravel by default when the user confirms his email, the user gets  logged in the automatically.
I want to change that default behaviour so that the user does not get auto logged in.

Can someone suggest me please, how to do it?

Thank You.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: It's part of laravel functionality I din't add there any of may code: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/verification

Comment: oh soryy , i thought you did by yourself because you did not mention it you r on updated version

Comment: you can follow my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you see your `VerficationController` laravel use trait `use VerifiesEmails`; which is actually responsible for verifying user and redirecting to home.

Read more about traits [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

You can override the `verify()` method from this trait with your own definition in your `VerificationController`

The method doing redirect is `verify`.
All you have do is right following code in your controller(`VerificationController`)

```
public function verify(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->route('id') != $request->user()->getKey()) {
            throw new AuthorizationException;
        }

        if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            return redirect($this->redirectPath());
        }
       
        // markEmailAsVerified() is updating your database
        if ($request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
           //here do what ever you want to do.
            event(new Verified($request->user()));
        }
        
        // simply redirect to login here
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('message','Your email is successfully verified. Please Login Here');
    }
```

Comment: I know the concept of trait but I can't see a method where that login proces happens.

Comment: `event( new Verified($request->user()) )` i guess this event is doing.
you just have to override and do it as you want.